# Akka. How to complete a stream with Source.actorRef?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I'd like to complete a stream with predefined messages count:

```
Source.actorRef(Integer.MAX_VALUE, OverflowStrategy.fail())
    .limit(1)
    .to(Sink.onComplete(System.out::println))
    .run(materializer);
    .tell("Do Complete!", ActorRef.noSender());
```

From the limit method documentation:

> Completes when **the defined number of elements has been taken** or
>   upstream completes

Why does stream not complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the documentation for `take` , not `limit`.

And indeed, you should use `take` to solve your problem.

Comment: PS: in the javadoc the limit method has the same description (http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Source.html#limit-int-)

Comment: copy-paste error, I guess..
this doc page is usually more reliable http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java/stream/stages-overview.html